# Black Ops: how to avoid the "Set optimal settings" and "Run in safe mode" dialogs?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops

is there a way to avoid the following two dialogs?

[image]
[image]

I always select 'No' but the dialogs kept appearing.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well it sounds like the real issue is the game crashing/closing improperly. You should look into that and if you can fix it, these dialogs shouldn't show up.
Take a look at this link, it seems pretty extensive: http://segmentnext.com/2010/11/09/call-of-duty-black-ops-crashes-freezes-errors-sound-fixes/

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this solution

First if you have downloaded the game from Steam, try to run the game from the installation directory. If you get the dll missing error, download that dll file into you Black Ops installation directory and run the game. You can download any or every DLL File from here.

Do an integrity check to see if you have missed any files, Steam will automatically download these files. Start the Singleplayer mode, and then you can go into Multiplayer. This may fix this issue for some.